# java indexof allways return -1

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I have this line of code

`test.remove(Arrays.asList(test).indexOf(großezahl))`

Practically I want to remove the occurence ''großezahl'' in an ArrayList called ''test'' removed. Problem is, everytime i tried this code I ran into the same problem

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Maybe there is a better way of solving the problem, but this really bugs me. If anyone wants to try my examples, ''test'' is [2, 3, 4] and ''großezahl'' is 3. The ArrayList also consists only of integers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since `test` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, `Arrays.asList(test)` will create a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Since a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`, only contains instances of `ArrayList<Integer>`, it can never contain `3`. `indexOf` always returns -1.

You should not call `asList` at all:

```
test.remove(test.indexOf(grossezahl));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Arrays.asList(test)` it returns a `List` of `ArrayLists`, not `Integers`.
And of course you can't find element `großezahl` there (that's why `indexOf()` returns -1), because it contents only your `test` `ArrayList` as it's element.
If you want to remove "`großezahl`" element from `test`:

if `großezahl` is of `Integer` type and not of `int` you should call `test.remove(großezahl);` .

If `großezahl` is of type `int`, you can call either `test.remove(new Integer(großezahl));` or `test.remove(test.indexOf(großezahl));`
I hope it will help you!